# Create folder/Sub-folder in Code-igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a Drupal dev and new to code-igniter or any such php frameworks.

Now i have to modify an existing application done on codeigniter and the structure must be as follows:

1. example.com/motors
2. example.com/motors/car-for-sale
3. example.com/motors/car-for-rent etc.

Before it has only one url *example.com/motors* and i want to create more urls as mentioned above.

In the application\views\content folder i have the following structure:

**application\views\content\motors.php**

**application\views\content\motors**

**application\views\content\motors\car-for-sale.php**

In the application\controller folder i have the following structure:

**application\controller\motors.php**

**application\controller\motors\motors.php**

**application\controller\motors\car-for-sale.php**

I want to get the url example.com/motors & example.com/motors/car-for-sale from the files resides in the motors folder.Also how can i set a default file to load when i open **example.com/motors**?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a (controllers) directory that matches the name of a controller class at the same level. That is, since you have a *controllers/motors.php*, the files under *controllers/motors/** will never be reached.

Instead (and this is the answer to your second question), you should set the *default_controller* name and rename `controllers/motors.php` to `controllers/motors/<default_controller>.php`.

Note that the *default_controller* setting points to a controller *name* (not a file location) and is applied to all directories. That is, if you set it to 'Default', then *controllers/Default.php* will be used when you open `http://domain.tld/` and *controllers/motors/Default.php* will be used if you open `http://domain.tld/motors/`.

Also, your controller names MUST start with a capital letter, so *default.php* would be incorrect and should be *Default.php* instead. This might be working for you on Windows right now (because of its case-insensitive file system), but as soon as you upload your site to a Linux (or other UNIX-based) host, any classes with file names that don't start with a capital letter won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comment.I changed the names of the files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to build a CodeIgniter site with a completely different paradigm from what it is designed around.

The structure you are after can be set up using the `routes.php` file within `application/config`

In there, you can set routes to go to any location needed, so for you, something like:

```
$routes['motors/cars-for-sale'] => 'motors/cars_for_sale';
$routes['motors/cars-for-rent'] => 'motors/cars_for_rent';
```

Then in `application/controller` you'd have a `Motors.php` file, which starts:

```
class Motors extends CI_Controller{
```

And also has the functions `cars_for_sale` and `cars_for_rent`

The mappings in routes sets this to link together.

In order to get the views you want for any given route, in the controller function, you'd have:

```
$this->load->view('path/to/view/file', $array_of_data); // view path does not need the .php extension
```

I'd recommend having a look and possibly even a follow through of the [CodeIgniter tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html) in their documentation

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I created the url motors/used-car-for-sale .It shows the result as per the query. Now i need the method to show a page when i try http://example.com/motors. In this page i gave the list with out any criteria. I think i can create an index page inside the motors folder. I tried this and failed. i want to remove the motors.php inside the controller & view/content folder and after i will load the url like example.com/motors ,
example.com/motors/car-for-sale.

Comment: I managed to display items in example.com/motors/. Thanks again.